# SSH Fingerprint with Golang

Tags: go, ssh

How can I get my own ssh fingerprint with Go?

```
Finger, err := ssh.**
log.Println(Finger)
// 12:f8:7e:78:61:b4:bf:e2:de:24:15:96:4e:d4:72:53
```

Comment: Fingerprint of what? Your remote server, your local ssh server, a particular publickey in your ssh-agent, a local file? (and BTW, that pattern you're showing as an example is the an md5 fingerprint which isn't used any longer)

Comment: @JimB My local machine. I need it to use with terraform.

Comment: @JimB  https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/r/droplet.html

Comment: The keys to access the droplet don't have anything to do with the publickey of your local machine's ssh daemon. If you're trying to define the key to access a droplet, you need to add that key in DigitalOcean, and then refer to it either by ID or or fingerprint, both of which they provide.

Comment: I'd have to review the `ssh` package to see what it offers but if all else fails you can just run the command you noted above from your go code and read off stdout.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Thanks! I have done it, but could not find it!

Comment: @CESCO: ok, and example of what you're actually trying to do helps!

Comment: @JimB  As evanmcdonnal mentioned, I am currently running the code with go and reading off stdout. I am writing a cli to deploy self-hosted Kubernetes on DO.

Comment: @CESCO: I'm still going to repeat that the keys in DO are _not_ referencing your local keys, but keys you registered with them, and you can get the fingerprint they're using via their API (with the ID). In terraform we would normally reference the key from elsewhere in the config like `ssh_keys  = ["${digitalocean_ssh_key.foobar.id}"]`, so there's no reason to try and calculate the fingerprint.

Comment: @JimB you are right!

Comment: @JimB looks like you cant use this https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/r/ssh_key.html on two different projects. I get `422 SSH Key is already in use on your account`

Comment: @CESCO: that's correct, you can't register the same key a second time. You should have a single terraform config/module handling that key, or even better, use separate keys for separate projects.

Comment: @JimB So it turns out that is wiser to create an ssh key with go http://stackoverflow.com/a/21171325/3074508 and then create a DO ssh_key block referencing it. Does that sounds better?

Comment: @CESCO: Is it wiser? Managing keys is usually left up to the user for a reason, since there are other security considerations. How are you going to securely manage that new private key? Are you going to encrypt the private key, and how would you do that? What if the user prefers ED25519 keys, or requires 4096 bit keys instead of 2048? Not saying you can't do it, but you have to be very careful in this area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A key signature is is just a cryptographic hash of the unencoded key data in ssh wire format.

Here is a basic example of parsing an ssh key from the OpenSSH format public key, and getting an MD5 fingerprint:

```
key, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/to/id_rsa.pub")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

parts := strings.Fields(string(key))
if len(parts) < 2 {
    log.Fatal("bad key")
}

k, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(parts[1])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fp := md5.Sum([]byte(k))
fmt.Print("MD5:")
for i, b := range fp {
    fmt.Printf("%02x", b)
    if i < len(fp)-1 {
        fmt.Print(":")
    }
}
fmt.Println()
```

Comment: perfect! Just need to append the : every two characther to consider as the right answer.

Comment: I am still having trouble getting the final result into a string. @JimB

Comment: @CESCO: what exactly are you having trouble with? The example prints to stdout, but the string manipulation is pretty much the same.

Comment: got it `str:= strings.ToUpper(hex.EncodeToString(fp[:]))`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to parse the key using the ssh package and then use FingerprintLegacyMD5 in order to generate the fingerprint. See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46430102/1601137

Answer (score 1):

In case that you need a fingerprint of an `rsa.PublicKey` you can use the `ssh.FingerprintLegacyMD5()` function (or the `ssh.FingerprintSHA256()` one).

The only issue is that you have to convert the `rsa.PublicKey` to an `ssh.PublicKey` which can be done via the `ssh.NewPublicKey()` function.

```
func getFingerprint(key *rsa.PublicKey) string {
    pubKey, _ := ssh.NewPublicKey(key)
    return ssh.FingerprintLegacyMD5(pubKey)
}
```