# Go - How to Generate an SSH PublicKey Fingerprint from PublicKey, the PublicKey's type maybe is one of [ rsa dsa ssh-rsa ssh-dss ecdsa ]

Tags: go, ssh-keys

I only have a PublicKey string, How do I get the PublicKey Fingerprint?
I have got some idea form https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/crypto/+/32814, but I do not know how to
implement ssh.PublicKey interface.

Comment: There is no single fingerprint for a public key. Fingerprints are just hashes of the public key and you are free to choose any hash algorithm. The Go standard library already has public key implementations for popular key types in the respective crypto/* packages. I doubt you have to implement your own.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want to use ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey from the ssh package to load the key:

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ParseAuthorizedKey

That will give you a public key which you can call ssh.FingerprintLegacyMD5 on in order to get the fingerprint (assuming here you want the md5).

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#FingerprintLegacyMD5
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#FingerprintSHA256

```
func main() {
    // Read a key from a file in authorized keys file line format
    // This could be an rsa.pub file or a line from authorized_keys
    pubKeyBytes := []byte(`ssh-rsa AAAABMYKEY...ABC me@myplace.local`)

    // Parse the key, other info ignored
    pk, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(pubKeyBytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Get the fingerprint
    f := ssh.FingerprintLegacyMD5(pk)

    // Print the fingerprint
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", f)
}
```

There are two fingerprint functions provided, not sure which one you need.